# Select partialy matching rows from two differernt table in KDB?

Tags: kdb

assume I have the following two tables

**Table1**

```
symbol ric
--------------  
AAA    AATSA.AS   
AALB   AALB.AS  
AJAX   AJAX.AS  
AMG    AMG.AS
```

**Table2**

```
Title               Ticker
ARCELORMITTAL REG   AAA.AS  
TC EURO EQ          TEET.AS
HAL TRUST           HAL.AS 
TETRAGON FIN GROUP  TFG.AS
```

what is the query that I need in order to get all Table1.symbol that are partially matching with Table2.Ticker?

for example in the following two tables I should be getting **AAA** from **Table1.symbol** since it is partially matching with **AAA.AS** from **Table2.Ticker**

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the only logic here is that `Table2.Ticker` can be split by `.` and that can be matched against `Table1.symbol`.

First off, you can split Ticker:

```
q)update fragment:`$("." vs' string Ticker)[;0] from `Table2
`Table2
q)Table2
Title             Ticker  fragment
----------------------------------
ARCELORMITTAL REG AAA.AS  AAA
TC EURO EQ        TEET.AS TEET
```

Although I could have called `fragment` `symbol` instead I have it as a separate column for illustration. You also need the column `fragment` to join on on `Table1`:

```
q)update fragment:symbol from `Table1
`Table1
q)Table1
symbol ric      fragment
------------------------
AAA    AATSA.AS AAA
AALB   AALB.AS  AALB
```

So now we can either do a [`uj`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#uj-ujf-union-join) or [`lj`](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/joins/#lj-ljf-left-join) - you should look these up on the reference pages. Just to use `uj` in this case to see the whole shebang:

```
q)(`fragment xkey Table1) uj (`fragment xkey Table2)
fragment| symbol ric      Title             Ticker
--------| -----------------------------------------
AAA     | AAA    AATSA.AS ARCELORMITTAL REG AAA.AS
AALB    | AALB   AALB.AS
TEET    |                 TC EURO EQ        TEET.AS
```

---

**On a sidenote...** Joining Bloomberg and RIC symbols is a nightmare :-) Ultimately you're going to have to have tables that join up ISINS, RICs and Bloomberg tickers bearing in mind RICs and tickers change over time.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I wasted so many hours trying to find the answer. Also a small correction I think queries should be without the " ` " symbol before the table names. One last thing, I have been going around in circle to get something as simple as this to work, do you know any good resources that can get me to understand kdb in a better way ?

Comment: @Kareem the table name that has the `\`` updates the table in place. Otherwise you get a copy of the table returned, with the original table untouched. In terms of resources I would highly recommend Q for Mortals first. There are also a bunch of other tutorials too, see this site: http://code.kx.com/wiki/Tutorials

Comment: Thanks, will surely look at it.

Answer (score 0):

In cases when there is no demarcation on how to split the symbol to do the exact match, you might want to search it using `like` :

```
q)select from t1 where any each t2[`Ticker] like/:(string[symbol],\:"*")
symbol ric
---------------
AAA    AATSA.AS
```

Though it is not an ideal solution and should be avoided by understanding the data and splitting the symbols to use the joins as described in the accepted answer.